# GNU Emacs is crashing with -nw

Tags: c, linux, emacs

When I run emacs with `-nw` option, the emacs really open, but I can't do more nothing. As if the user input is blocked and no keyboard signal is received and/or interpreted. I've tried run without load .emacs file and some other behaviors:

> emacs -nw -Q --no-desktop --debug-ini foo.c

But makes no difference and strangely the GUI-version(using Gtk) is working fine.

My gnu-emacs version is `GNU Emacs 23.3.1`

Any help to help to fix it is very appreciated.

Comment: What shell are you running it in and what terminal emulator?

Comment: I have tried by using `konsole` and `xterm`.

Comment: Check that your terminal isn't grabbing input (such as Ctrl and Alt keys from you)

Comment: not.. the xemacs is working fine `xemacs -nw foo.c`

Comment: Off-topic, but I would try running `strace -p` on emacs' pid to see if you can determine where it's stuck (or starting emacs with `strace -o logfile.txt emacs -nw`).

Comment: cant reproduce it with GNU emacs 24.2.1. maybe you can update your emacs to a new version?

Comment: @R..: By using `strace -p` I get the following message: `Process 2318 attached - interrupt to quit` and when I back to emacs and press some key, the `strace` print `--- {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} (I/O possible) ---
sigreturn()                             = ? (mask now [])
`

Comment: update is my last solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t find the error. I just updated emacs to 24.2.1 and it works fine now.

Comment: @Synetech: Thanks for the correction. English isn't my native language speaker.

Comment: No problem, that’s why we are allowed to edit. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ~/.emacs config file that might be hanging Emacs and not Xemacs?

Is your env variable $TERM set?  Have you reconfigured any of your terminal settings (maybe using 'tset', like ROWS or COLS)?  Does 'reset' help?

It sounds like other apps that use vt100 emulation and curses are OK (e.g. Xemacs).  I assume vi works normally?

Comment: 1) not. 2)yeah, it's defined with `xterm` value. 3)`tset` and `reset` didn't difference. 4)hmm not sure if `vt100` how do I check? and yeah, the vi is working fine.